# .play() function not working on safari browser with audio tag

Tags: php, jquery, safari, html5-audio

I am building a website http://directhearingtest.com/ and it's working fine and playing audio files on click using jquery but in safari browser IPad it's giving the following error

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('audio#audio2')[0].play()')

I have tried many solutions but not solving it. Here is the HTML script

```
<audio id="audio2" > 
    <source src="tunes/500 HZ/20.wav" type="audio/mpeg" >
</audio>

<a  id="start_sample" class="text-white font-weight-bold pl-3 pr-3 pt-2 pb-2 p " style="cursor: 
  pointer; background-color:#2e7ed5; border-radius: 25px; border: 6px solid; font-family: sans-serif; 
  ">Play sample tones</a>
```

Here is the Jquery Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#start_sample').click(function(){
    $('audio#audio2')[0].play();
 });
});
```

Please help out me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try a different format. Wav files may not be supported.

Comment: tried .mp3 file also. but getting same errors 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating ' $('audio#audio2')[0].play()')

Comment: @HaseebAhad it will not work by just changing the extension you need to convert the file to that extension first.

Comment: I changed the source file too, not just changed the extension... used a new mp3 file

Comment: I am not able to replicate this issue. do you have the issue here? http://getbsm.com/wav/

Comment: @ARWVISIONS its working fine on chrome browser, but the same error on Safari 
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('audio#audio2')[0].play()')

Comment: works fine on all versions so my safari. Tested multiple versions. I would try some different devices.

Comment: can you provide a direct link to a page with an audio file? I don't want to register to test you config.

Comment: @ARWVISIONS here is the link http://directhearingtest.com/playsampletone

Comment: Works fine on my ipad :/

Comment: i am using safari on windows? is there any issue with it I think?  @ARWVISIONS

Comment: can't help you there, I don't use or support safari for windows. Don't even have it installed.